# Removing services of a product using ajax request deosnt update quote total price

Tags: quote

i have written a code to remove related services while removing a product from cart. Even though the product and its services are getting removed from quote_item table, the total price in `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')` or `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` isn't getting updated.

```
    foreach ( $quote->getItemsCollection() as $item ) {  
       if ($item->getSwType() == 'service' || $item->getDeliveryParentId()) {  
            $item->isDeleted(true);  
            $quote->removeItem($item->getItemId());  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to call

```
$quote->collectTotals();
```

and possibly

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

if quote is already collected. Be prepared tho as Magento is not expecting that this method is called multiple times and so do lot of 3rd party extensions who add something to totals. So you need to verify your totals as well if they are correct .

Comment: No i had tried this already. It dint work.

Comment: i am deleting the product then removing the service items. If i place the removing items above deleting the product, it worked. But many other condition breaks and its not the right way. i suspect after calling deleteProduct() then removing the service is not getting updated

Comment: @Anusha after calling `collectTotals()` did you call `$quote->save()`?

Comment: @Marius i did call `$quote->save()` after `collectTotals()`. But it dint give me correct total